# SQL query for complex filtering

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have SQL schema something like this.

```
select Id, AccountId, GradeLevelStart, GradeLevelEnd from AccountProfile
```

Which contains data as shown in this snapshot.

[image]

Here GradeLevelStart, and GradeLevelEnd is Id of Gradelevels. see below query and it's data.

```
select Id, Name, Abbreviation from GradeLevel
```

[image]

I have created one filter which works using between operator.
Flow is something like this,

- user choose a grade 1st, 2nd whatever and this query will return **all the accounts which comes in between for that grade and it's GradeLevelStart, GradeLevelEnd**.

Here is the query for it.

```
DECLARE @Grades NVARCHAR(100)
SET @Grades = '3'

    select AccountId, GradeLevelStart, GradeLevelEnd, glStart.Name, glStart.Abbreviation, glEnd.Name, glEnd.Abbreviation 
    from AccountProfile 
        left join GradeLevel glStart on glStart.ID = GradeLevelStart
        left join GradeLevel glEnd on glEnd.ID = GradeLevelEnd
    where @Grades IS NULL OR @Grades BETWEEN GradeLevelStart and GradeLevelEnd
```

> **What I am looking for?**

This all works fine till now, but it's not yet taking multiple @Grades for filtering.

So what I want is User gives input in a format like below query and **system should return all the accounts which has GradeLevelStart and GradeLevelEnd in between this @Grades**

```
SET @Grades = '3,13,'
```

**What I tried so far?**

- I have created temp table, and tried to use join but no luck since I don't know how to use between operator there.
- I have also used STRING_SPLIT, but it's of no use.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use String **Split Function** to achieve this:

```
DECLARE @Grades NVARCHAR(100)
SET @Grades = '3,13'

select AccountId, GradeLevelStart, GradeLevelEnd, glStart.Name, glStart.Abbreviation, 
glEnd.Name, glEnd.Abbreviation 
from AccountProfile 
left join GradeLevel glStart on glStart.ID = GradeLevelStart
left join GradeLevel glEnd on glEnd.ID = GradeLevelEnd
OUTER APPLY STRING_SPLIT(@Grades,',') s
where @Grades IS NULL OR (s.value) BETWEEN GradeLevelStart and GradeLevelEnd
```

Also, You can achieve the Same by using **XML Nodes** Instead of **STRING SPLIT**:

For your ref:

```
declare @S varchar(100) = 'Hello John Smith'

select 
n.r.value('.', 'varchar(50)')
from (select cast('<r>'+replace(@S, ' ', '</r><r>')+'</r>' as xml)) as s(XMLCol)
cross apply s.XMLCol.nodes('r') as n(r)
```

Comment: looks like outer apply will work. but I'm still looking for a best practise. let me know if there is any other way.